# Set function to specific address in PIC18F with the HI-TECH C compiler

Tags: pic, c, mplabx, hi-tech-compiler

I want to put a function in an specific address of memory like PIC C Compiler (`#org`).
I'm using MPLAB X, HI-TECH compiler and PIC18F4550.

In PIC C compiler:

```
#org 0x1000, 0x2000
void MyFunction()
{
}

//In other part of code I'll use: asm("goto 0x1000");
```

How to do this in MPLAB X with the HI-TECH compiler?

Comment: I don't understand why you'd need to.  You can reference the symbol `MyFunction` from assembly (maybe as `_MyFunction` depending on compiler).

Comment: Also, you should never ever ever "goto" a function, or "goto" anywhere outside your current function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC, you can set a function to an absolute address by using the "@" qualifier:

```
void MyFunction() @ 0x2A0
{
    ...
}
```

So the function `MyFunction` will be placed at address 0x2A0 in Program Memory.

Comment: Thanks @m.Alin, I worked. I'd like to ask you how to use `int address = 0x20; **asm("goto "___mktstr(addr));**` but If I use `asm("goto "___mktstr(0x20));` works. I want to use `goto` to go a specific address using addr variable, perhaps there is another option like goto_address(addr) in pic CCS compiler. Thank you.

Comment: The ___mktstr(x) macro [stringifies](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html) its argument. `___mktstr(0x20)` will return the string "0x20", but `___mktstr(addr)` will return the string "addr".

Comment: Thanks, but I still couldn't find a way to GO to a variable address. It looks like asm() argument must be char constant. 
Is there another solution to jump to an address using goto?

Comment: @jaspher I'm not experienced in assembly. You should ask a new question regarding that.

Answer (score -1):

use the linker command file to set the address of .text portion of MyFunction

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question. Please add further explanation.